# Convery URL parameterst o XML in Mule ESB

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, mule, mule-studio

I have a scenario where a REST service calls a SOAP webservice in back ground. I am looking for a way to construct and XML file (that will become request for SOAP) with some of the parameters in the URL.

GET call from URL

```
http://myurl/changeAddress?id=1001&name=Steve&salary=3
```

XML request for SOAP webserivce:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:unk="http://unknown.namespace/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <unk:changeAddress>
         <arg0>1001</arg0>
         <arg1>Steve</arg1>
      </unk:changeAddress>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried out MLE and I am able to extract key-value from URL. But not sure how do I construct an XML form those parameters.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Theres many options. XSLT, Jaxb or Datamapper transformers. One simple way just for that simple use case would be to use Groovy's XML MarkupBUilder or the MVEL parse-template transformer:

```
<scripting:transformer>
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text>
                    def writer = new StringWriter()
                    def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)

                    xml.'soap:Envelope'('xmlns:soap':'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/') {
                        'soap:Body'{
                            'unk:changeAddress'('xmlns:unk':'http://unknown.namespace/'){
                                'arg0'(message.inboundProperties.id)
                                'arg1'(message.inboundProperties.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return writer.toString()
                </scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach other than Ryan mentioned will be using set-payload directly
You can directly create the **SOAP** request in the **payload** and put the **inbound properties** like **id** and **name** in it dynamically like the following :-

```
 <set-payload value="&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:unk=&quot;http://unknown.namespace/&quot;&gt;&lt;soapenv:Header/&gt;&lt;soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;unk:changeAddress&gt;&lt;arg0&gt;#[message.inboundProperties.id]&lt;/arg0&gt;&lt;arg1&gt;#[message.inboundProperties.name]&lt;/arg1&gt;&lt;/unk:changeAddress&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Envelope&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

This will be **simple** and **dynamic** in creating **SOAP** request
So, the full example will be as follows :-

```
<flow name="setSOAPRequestFlow">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/changeAddress" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<set-payload value="&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:unk=&quot;http://unknown.namespace/&quot;&gt;&lt;soapenv:Header/&gt;&lt;soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;unk:changeAddress&gt;&lt;arg0&gt;#[message.inboundProperties.id]&lt;/arg0&gt;&lt;arg1&gt;#[message.inboundProperties.name]&lt;/arg1&gt;&lt;/unk:changeAddress&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Envelope&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>     
</flow>
```

Comment: Thats very messy and hard to maintain.

Comment: Yup .. but you can able to create it easily .. you just need to copy your SOAP request in the set-payload and put the inboundproperties in the args .. You can get better view of this data from your Graphical flow where if you select the set-payload you can see the SOAP request .. Anyways, you can use what you feel better